# your application has redirected loops in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

After writing code in global.asax this error ocured. If i keep a break point to check it was firing and spinning and eventually browser outcomes with the above responce["Your application has redirected loops"].
    `

```
 public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
       {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check  sessions here
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}`
```

Really funny but why this stupid error occuring again and again.Any Idea?

Comment: When you app starts, `Session["username"]` is null so it does a redirect, which fires the the ActionFilter. The value is still null so it does a redirect, which fires the ActionFilter. The value is still null so it ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i didn't read your question properly

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
       {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check  sessions here
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Accounts" },
                    { "Action", "Login" }
                    });

        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: already kept [AllowAnonymous] attribute to Login ActionResult in Account Controller

Comment: can you tell me what all attibutes are applied to the login page and in what order ?

Comment: [Session Expire] at controller level.

Comment: Yeah its working without error but i kept session time out to 1 minute, previously when user clicks after 1 minute it used to show error because of session null but now no error but one more problem is page not redirecting to login .Its in the same page

Comment: [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        Repository _rep = new Repository();

        
       
      
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `ActionFilter` from `AccountController`

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to "~/Account/Login" the code of OnActionExecuting will be called again so `HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null` is true and you have your redirect loop.

So, you need other condition for check this